# Postgres - ERROR: prepared statement "S_1" already exists

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pgbouncer

When executing batch queries via JDBC to pgbouncer, I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: prepared statement "S_1" already exists
```

I've found bug reports around the web, but they all seem to deal with Postgres 8.3 or below, whereas we're working with Postgres 9.

Here's the code that triggers the error:

```
this.getJdbcTemplate().update("delete from xx where username = ?", username);

this.getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate( "INSERT INTO xx(a, b, c, d, e) " + 
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
        ps.setString(1, value1);
        ps.setString(2, value2);
        ps.setString(3, value3);
        ps.setString(4, value4);
        ps.setBoolean(5, value5);
    }
    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() {
        return something();
    }
});
```

Anyone seen this before?

***Edit 1:***

This turned out to be a pgBouncer issue that occurs when using anything other than **session pooling**. We were using **transaction pooling**, which apparently can't support prepared statements. By switching to **session pooling**, we got around the issue.

Unfortunately, this isn't a good fix for our use case. We have two separate uses for pgBouncer: one part of our system does bulk updates which are most efficient as prepared statements, and another part needs many connections in very rapid succession. Since pgBouncer doesn't allow switching back and forth between **session pooling** and **transaction pooling**, we're forced to run two separate instances on different ports just to support our needs.

***Edit 2:***

I ran across [this link](http://pgfoundry.org/pipermail/pgbouncer-general/2010-February/000507.html), where the poster has rolled a patch of his own. We're currently looking at implementing it for our own uses if it proves to be safe and effective.

Comment: Maybe a pgbouncer problem? Or an outdated JDBC driver?

Comment: It's definitely a pgbouncer problem. We bypassed pgbouncer and hit Postgres directly, and the prepared statement works. The JDBC driver is the latest available.

Comment: Is there some setting that tells pgbouncer to reset connections on release back to the pool?  Sounds like you're reusing connetions that already have run the prepare before.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe there is. It's the connection pooling option. We use `transaction pooling`, which is supposed to release connections back to the pool immediately after a transaction ends.

Comment: It's not about releasing the connection, it's about resetting it.  If it doesn't do a reset on the connection then old things like prepared queries can still be there.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe how might that be achieved?

Comment: Take a look here: http://pgpool.projects.postgresql.org/pgpool-II/doc/pgpool-en.html#connection_pool_mode  Basically it depends on pg version, but  ABORT; DISCARD ALL; will work for all versions from 8.3 onward

Comment: `prepareThreshold=0` solved my issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This turned out to be a pgBouncer issue that occurs when using anything other than **session pooling**. We were using **transaction pooling**, which apparently can't support prepared statements. By switching to **session pooling**, we got around the issue.

Unfortunately, this isn't a good fix for our use case. We have two separate uses for pgBouncer: one part of our system does bulk updates which are most efficient as prepared statements, and another part needs many connections in very rapid succession. Since pgBouncer doesn't allow switching back and forth between **session pooling** and **transaction pooling**, we're forced to either run two separate instances on different ports just to support our needs, or to implement [this patch](http://pgfoundry.org/pipermail/pgbouncer-general/2010-February/000507.html). Preliminary testing shows it to work well, but time will tell if it proves to be safe and effective.

Comment: The link is dead, unfortunately. This is an archive snapshot: http://web.archive.org/web/20120222062130/http://pgfoundry.org/pipermail/pgbouncer-general/2010-February/000507.html

Comment: Could you create a separate pool for your bulk inserts in this case that uses session pooling and use the transaction pooling in another location or does this have some other negative consequence?

Answer (score 21):

Disabling prepared statements in JDBC.
The proper way to do it for JDBC is adding "prepareThreshold=0" parameter to connect string.

```
jdbc:postgresql://ip:port/db_name?prepareThreshold=0
```

Comment: worked for me - but perhaps it would be better to remove useAffectedRows=true from your answer? not necessary?

Comment: OK，just removed it

Answer (score 5):

## New, Better Answer

To discard session state and effectively forget the **"S_1"** prepared statement, use server_reset_query option in PgBouncer config.

## Old Answer

See http://pgbouncer.projects.postgresql.org/doc/faq.html#_how_to_use_prepared_statements_with_transaction_pooling

Switching into session mode is not an ideal solution. Transacion pooling is much more efficient. But for transaction pooling you need stateless DB calls.

I think you have three options:

1. Disable PS in jdbc driver,
2. manually deallocate them in your Java code,
3. configure pgbouncer to discard them on transaction end.

I would try option 1 or option 3 - depending on actual way in which your app uses them.

For more info, read the docs:

http://pgbouncer.projects.postgresql.org/doc/config.html (search for server_reset_query),

or google for this:

```
postgresql jdbc +preparethreshold
```

Comment: "When transaction pooling is used, the server_reset_query should be empty, as clients should not use any session features." Doesn't look like option 3 is possible. Option 1 isn't feasible for our use. Option 2 could possibly work, but how might that be accomplished?

Comment: It appears that `session_lifetime` may be the setting that causes the problem. We're experimenting with it now. I'll report back shortly.

Comment: @Chris: option 3 is possible - pgbouncer doc says what SHOULD be done in general, but in your case I would try it. 
Regarding option 2, see http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/x20921, and regarding option 1 - why not?

Comment: new link for server_reset_query docs : 
https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html#what-should-my-serverresetquery-be

Answer (score 1):

In our case the issue was not related to pgbouncer. Since we did were not able to append `prepareThreshold=0` to the URL what we did to fix was the following

View the prepared statements

```
select * from pg_prepared_statements;
```

Deallocate the faulty table

```
select * from pg_prepared_statements;
deallocate "S_1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PgBouncer 1.21.0 it now supports protocol level named prepared statements, which is what JDBC uses. You can turn this support on by setting `max_prepared_statements` to a non-zero value. For details check the docs: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#max_prepared_statements

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, we have pgbouncer configurated in transaction level, we were using psql 11.8, we just upgraded the psql jar to the latest version, it got fixed.

Comment: Please post the answers to particular version of psql which ever user is asking because upgrading the psql may cause other issues and it would be difficult for user to understand. and try to correct/improvise the code which ever is posted in question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! - Dilip D
I have upgraded to postgres.jdbc.4.2-42..2.14 from postgres 8.4