# Laravel data mismatch error while using \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true

Tags: laravel, postgresql, pdo, pgbouncer

We have application build in Php Laravel and for the database we use postgres sql. And also on top of postgres we have configure pgBouncer to limit the maximum number of connections on server side by managing a pool of idle connections that can be used by any applications.

Now, we face the issue with the boolean values (True(0),False(1)) used in the application (Php Laravel). It gives below error when any CRUD operation is performed. In the below error column "revoked" is boolean type.

**column \"revoked\" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. (SQL: \"revoked\", \"created_at\") values (0, 2020-02-07 06:09:06)**

Now after exploring, I came to know that boolean values needs to be consider to be string with the pgBouncer. So I have made changes in the **connection.php** file, located in "**\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database**". I have change the code to consider the boolean value as mentioned below.

```
public function bindValues($statement, $bindings)
{
    foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
        //if(is_bool($value))
        $statement->bindValue(
            is_string($key) ? $key : $key + 1, $value,
            //is_int($value) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR
            is_int($value) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : is_bool($value) ? PDO::PARAM_STR : PDO::PARAM_STR
        );
    }
}
```

After the above changes the error with the boolean values was solved.

But, now I am facing strange issues on the server, when I check the database log error I consistently get the below error.

**ERROR:  prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000001" already exists
STATEMENT:  set names 'utf8'
ERROR:  prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000001" does not exist
STATEMENT:  DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000001**

It really was strange, and after exploring the internet I have done the below changes in my **database.php** file, to disable the prepare statements.

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',            
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        'options' => [
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        ]
]
```

The reason behind seeting **ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true** is becasue I have set "**Transaction**" mode in "**pgbouncer.ini**" file.

Now, to make prepared statements work in **Transaction** mode would need PgBouncer to keep track of them internally, which it does not do. So only way to keep using PgBouncer in this mode is to disable prepared statements in the client, which in my case is PHP Laravel and I have already handle it in the "**database.php**" file when the connection is made as shown in above code.

I have tried all the options, which are given in **http://www.pgbouncer.org/faq.html#how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-transaction-pooling** but it doesnot solve the **prepare statment error** shown in the database log.

**ERROR:  prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000001" already exists
STATEMENT:  set names 'utf8'
ERROR:  prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000001" does not exist
STATEMENT:  DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000001**

Please guide me on the same and what further settings are required for the error. Those errors are on the client production server and we cannot go ahead with those errors in production server.

Please give me your valuable feedback at the earliest as I am facing the issue since 5 days and try with all the options that come across.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the answer suit to you?

Comment: No, still I am not getting a proper answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) First, you need to change the PDO option you are giving in the options in the pgsql array of your database.php the right way is as given below.

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5434'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),           
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        ]       
        ]
```

2) Second, and the most important thing is to make sure that you use set the "ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES" to "true" with each database connection you try to connect in your **Database.php** file.

For example,

```
'test' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('test', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('test', '5434'),
        'database' => env('DB_TEST_DATABASE', 'test'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'test'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        ]           
    ],
'test1' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('test1', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('test1', '5434'),
        'database' => env('DB_TEST1_DATABASE', 'test1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'test'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        ]           
    ]
```

Please make sure to use the "ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES" to true for each database connection you make in your application, in your comments you make connection with only "pgsql" which emphasis for postgres sql connection only, and not with the database that your application communicates which is in postgres.

Hope this helps you to resolve your query. Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 4):

First you never need to modify the vendor code, instead you can use attribute casting from your model.

**From [laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)**

> The $casts property on your model provides a convenient method of converting attributes to common data types. The $casts property should be an array where the key is the name of the attribute being cast and the value is the type you wish to cast the column to. The supported cast types are: integer, real, float, double, decimal:, string, boolean, object, array, collection, date, datetime, and timestamp. When casting to decimal, you must define the number of digits (decimal:2).
>
> To demonstrate attribute casting, let's cast the is_admin attribute,
>   which is stored in our database as an integer (0 or 1) to a boolean
>   value:

So in your case you will need to cast `revoked` to bool by adding to your **Eloquent model** the `$casts` property as follows:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'revoked' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```

And for your pgBouncer issue it seems that pgBouncer have an internal issue with **transaction pooling** and **prepared statements**,

**From: [stackoverflow.com/a/7612639/7047493](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7612639/7047493)**

> This turned out to be a pgBouncer issue that occurs when using anything other than session pooling. We were using transaction pooling, which apparently can't support prepared statements. By switching to session pooling, we got around the issue.

Comment: FYI, casting didn't fix the "is of type boolean but expression is of type integer".

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers fully worked in our case.  In our setup (Laravel + PostgreSQL + pgBouncer), we had enabled these 2 settings in the database.php file.  The goal was to make our php backend compatible with `pgBouncer` and that's what we had done:

```
    // database.php
    'options' => array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
    ), 
    'binary_parameters' => 'yes', // not sure if this one is necessary
```

These 2 settings partially worked, meaning we were able to run our backend without getting the `prepared statement does not exist` anymore.  Unfortunately for us, we were then getting the `datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column “xxx” is of type boolean but expression is of type integer` just like Nileshsinh Rathod.

Hopefully for us, we came across this [post](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/2005#issuecomment-619786670) on Github which fixed everything for us.  The goal is to override the default PostgresConnector.
And here is a recap of what we did:

- Add these 3 files in our project:

  - https://github.com/umbrellio/laravel-pg-extensions/blob/master/src/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php
  - https://github.com/umbrellio/laravel-pg-extensions/blob/master/src/UmbrellioPostgresProvider.php
  - https://github.com/umbrellio/laravel-pg-extensions/blob/master/src/PostgresConnection.php

    - Within this file, we only kept the `bindValues` and `prepareBindings` functions.
- Then, in our `config/app.php`, we registered the `PostgresProvider` like so

  ```
   'providers' => [
       App\Providers\ScPostgresProvider::class,
   ],
  ```
- Finally, we commented out this line in our AppServiceProvider file in order to make sure only the new one would be registered

  ```
   public function register()
   {
       // not used anymore since we use our our own connector
       // $this->app->bind('db.connector.pgsql', OldPostgresConnector::class);
   }
  ```

Thanks a lot to the post of Umbrellio team on Github and hope this answer will help others!