# Laravel query builder casts boolean to integer

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm using Laravel Framework (8.26) and PHP 8.0.5

My database is Postgresql (12.3)

This is my schema (cities table):

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint |  | not null |  |
| is_active | boolean |  | not null | true |

It also has lots of other fields which are not relevant to my question.

I've created a model for this table:

```
class City extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'cities';
}
```

Then when I use the query builder:

```
City::where('is_active', true)->get();
```

It raises an error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer LINE 1: select * from "cities" where "is_active" = $1 ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cities" where "is_active" = 1)
```

Why does it cast the field from boolean to integer? As you see, I explicitly passed `true` in second argument but Laravel converts the value to `1` and Postgres returns an error. However, when I run the raw query with "is_active = true" it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by an update to php 8.0.5.
You need to downgrade to PHP 8.0.4 or wait for 8.0.6.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/37215

Answer (score 3):

```
City::where('is_active','=' ,'true')->get();
```

Comment: It solved my problem but how? Why should we use 'true' as a string instead of true as a boolean ?!

Comment: If you're using booleans while inserting or updating data, laravel will convert them, but it can't do that while fetching records because it has no knowledge of the data types it reads - @FarhadKousha

Comment: @FarhadKousha https://stackoverflow.com/a/60751986/15648920

Comment: We're facing the same issues, this is quite absurd because we already have a huge system and now this is will need for us to do some refactor.