# PgBouncer with spring boot and postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, pgbouncer

I researched for spring boot, PostgreSQL and pgbouncer example and cannot find anywhere.

Do you know can we integrate pgbouncer with spring `javax.sql.DataSource`?

Can you share with me any page that can I take reference. When I look to Pgbouncer page cannot find example?

Comment: You just setup the database with a JDBC URL that poins to the pgBouncer server and port. Spring//JDBC won't even know that it's not a Postgres database but a load balancer.

Comment: my postgre host localhost port 5432 but pgbouncer is host 127.0.0.1 port xxx you mean I only change localhost to127.0.01 and port right? thats enough?

Comment: That should be enough, yes (and it's Postgres, not "postgre")

Comment: yes thank you ,but I get the error "prepared statement "S_24" already exists

Comment: For that error, see [Postgres - ERROR: prepared statement “S_1” already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611926/postgres-error-prepared-statement-s-1-already-exists)