# Psycopg 3 & SQLAlchemy 2: what would cause DuplicatePreparedStatement in normal operation?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, timescaledb, psycopg3

We are using SQLAlchemy in our application to interact with a TimescaleDB database with Psycopg as the database driver.

Recently we started seeing this error every time the application tries to select from the database:

```
psycopg.errors.DuplicatePreparedStatement: prepared statement "_pg3_3" already exists
```

No change to the application was deployed, and overall database load is very low.

Apparently there is *something* wrong in our application, but I am not an expert in any of these technologies. I can identify when the errors first appeared in our logs, but I cannot identify any change in activity or behavior that might point to a root cause.

My questions are:

1. What might cause this to happen during otherwise-normal operation, not under heavy load? Is this possibly a bug in one of the underlying libraries?
2. What is the recommended way to remediate this without significant downtime? Do I need to manually log in as an admin user and `DEALLOCATE` this `_pg_3` prepared statement? Do I need to restart the Python app workers?
3. What should be done in order to prevent this from happening again?

The relevant code looks something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime as Datetime
from typing import Any

from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession as BaseAsyncSession, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

from ..config import settings


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    type_annotation_map = {
        Datetime: TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
    }


async_engine = create_async_engine(
    settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
    isolation_level="READ COMMITTED",
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    pool_size=20,
    pool_recycle=3600,
    max_overflow=5,
)


AsyncSession = async_sessionmaker(async_engine, autobegin=False)


class SensorRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sensor_records"

    ...  # attributes here


async def fetch_prev_record(session: BaseAsyncSession, ...):
    query = select(SensorRecord)
    return ...  # more SQL and logic here
```

Update: I ended up simply re-deploying the Python application with a blue/green deployment. This seems to have fixed the problem, presumably by causing all connection sessions to be refreshed and thereby dropping these "stuck" prepared statements. However I want to leave this question open because I want to understand the actual cause, to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Are you using pgbouncer or similar?

Comment: Yes @snakecharmerb, this is a Managed TimescaleDB system and it is using PgBouncer.

Comment: I ended up simply re-deploying the Python application with a blue/green deployment. This seems to have fixed the problem, presumably by causing all connection sessions to be refreshed and thereby dropping these "stuck" prepared statements. However I want to leave this question open because I want to understand the actual cause, to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: PgBouncer could be the problem - see the warning [here](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/prepare.html#prepared-statements).  Also [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7611926/5320906).

Comment: @snakecharmerb it looks like Psycopg converts "unnamed" single-use prepared statements to "named" multi-use prepared statements, and it's the latter that causes the problem: https://jpcamara.com/2023/04/12/pgbouncer-is-useful.html. Does that seem right?

Comment: I'm a little confused because this never happened until recently, and the only changes that were made were related to Datadog environment variables. Possibly some bug inside the Datadog tracer was preventing prepared statements from being reused, and removing that bug exposed this underlying incompatibility with Psycopg behavior... Or something else entirely. But I will try this `prepare_threshold=0` setting and/or using the database directly instead of PgBouncer to see if those fix the issue.

Comment: Looks about right, but it's not an area I have much experience with.