ERROR: prepared statement "S_25" already exists Spring Data + postgres
So the problem is that is not always happening i have to make like 5/10 api request and then i get this error , then maybe for another 5 request i don't get the error then again the same error... funny thing is that i already tried and i don't get this error for every api.
PS. sometimes it even works correctly for a lot  and then again for some reason i get the error
ERROR: prepared statement "S_25" already exists
2024-07-18T17:40:04.358+02:00 ERROR 65632 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select c1_0.id,c1_0.gdp,c1_0.location_id,l1_0.id,lj1_0.id,lj1_0.img_name,l1_0.location_type,l1_0.x,l1_0.y,c1_0.max_population,c1_0.name,c1_0.population,c1_0.stage from city c1_0 join location l1_0 on l1_0.id=c1_0.location_id left join location_jobs lj1_0 on lj1_0.id=l1_0.location_jobs_id where c1_0.location_id=?] [ERROR: prepared statement "S_25" already exists] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: prepared statement "S_25" already exists

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LocationJobsServiceImpl implements LocationJobsService {

    private final LocationJobsRepository locationJobsRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public List<LocationJobsNoLocationsDto> getAllLocationJobs() {
        return locationJobsRepository.findAll().stream().map(locationJobs -> {
            LocationJobsNoLocationsDto locationJobsNoLocationsDto = new LocationJobsNoLocationsDto();
            locationJobsNoLocationsDto.setId(locationJobs.getId());
            locationJobsNoLocationsDto.setJobDtos(locationJobs.getJobs().stream().map(job -> modelMapper.map(job, JobDto.class)).toList());
            return locationJobsNoLocationsDto;
        }).toList();
    }
}

As i said before i tried other apis from the same app and not all of them have this error, + i used the same security config from another app and in that one i didn't have any problem.
Using Java 17, tried SpringBoot 3.2.2 / 3.3.1, postgresql 42.7.2, Supabase, Win 11

Just ask your database. Postgres 42 surely has the answer.

Let me guess: you are using a connection pool, right?

yes i am using springboot which as default is using hikaricp

so from what i understand by default, the PostgreSQL JDBC driver uses server-side prepared statements and for some reasons this didn't worked well with my supabase + spring app, to solve this problem for now i added  prepareThreshold=0 to my db connection url and the problem is solved for now. worth to know is that this solution can have performance issues and make things a little bit slover(didn't seem to notice any in my app).

I believe I have the same issue with you, the error is same, this issue only happens when connecting Supabase database (in connection with  my local postgreSQL, works well). Also with some possibility to happen, 5/10 possibility. I read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611926/postgres-error-prepared-statement-s-1-already-exists , it sees related with pgbouncer (on supabase?). I will try the solution: prepareThreshold=0, I have same concern on the performance.

I also found this "Some session-based Postgres features such as prepared statements are not available with this option." on supabase document. So another solution might be use port 5432 instead of 6543.
